# how to fixed the only one "li"?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have number of ul formed as a table. I want to fix the first "li" of each "ul" while scrolling.

i have done some work but can't able to fix the issue,

Here jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/PpYpa/2/

Please help me out from the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this...

```
ul {........}

ul li:first-child {position: fixed;}
```

This will fix your problem and is supported in most modern browsers.